# how to create a class with a variable that could have one of two types angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, object

I want to create a class to define a type of data. I want to restrict the data types of the fields in it. But the problem is that I want the 'value field to have one of two types depending on a particular configuration.

I will make multiple object of this class, and some of them have value as a string and others as an object.

```
export class Raw {
    'enabled': boolean;
    'value': -------> string/object <-------;
    'data': object;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types):

```
export class Raw {
    value: string | object;
}
```

<sub>**Note**: there's no need to 'quote' your property names unless they are otherwise invalid [identifiers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Identifier) (e.g. they contain spaces).</sub>